# DevExpress XtraGrid LayoutView - how to show images

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a data table with two field: `skin_name` and `image_path`. The sample skin images are stored on the HDD.

Now, I would like to show the skins in a GridControl via LayoutView (Carousel mode).

I loaded the data in the gridcontrol, now, how could I show the images too?

I don't want to store the images in the database.

Could you perhaps post sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the following KB article:
[**A2707** - How to display external images in grid columns if the data source only contains links to the images](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A2707.aspx).

Sample code for this article: [**E538**](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E538.aspx)

Comment: thanks, it was not so easy for me, but at the end, I managed this.